# Why are the number of blessings in the Amidah linked to Psalm 29?

Tags: blessing, shemoneh-esrei, shemos-sacred-names, tehilim-psalms

[The Gemoro in Berochos 28b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.28b.16?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) asks about the 18 blessings in the Amidah:

> גמ׳ הני שמונה עשרה כנגד מי
>
> Corresponding to what were these eighteen blessings instituted?

The Gemoro offers three answers:

> אמר רבי הלל בריה דרבי שמואל בר נחמני {1} כנגד שמונה עשרה אזכרות שאמר
>   דוד בהבו לה׳ בני אלים רב יוסף אמר {2} כנגד שמונה עשרה אזכרות שבקריאת
>   שמע אמר רבי תנחום אמר רבי יהושע בן לוי {3} כנגד שמונה עשרה חוליות
>   שבשדרה
>
> Rabbi Hillel, son of Rabbi Shmuel bar Naḥmani, said: {1}
>   Corresponding to the eighteen mentions of God’s name that King David
>   said in the psalm: “Give unto the Lord, O you sons of might” (Psalms
>   29). Rav Yosef said {2}: Corresponding to the eighteen mentions of
>   God’s name in Shema. Rabbi Tanḥum said that Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi
>   said {3}: Corresponding to the eighteen vertebrae in the spine beneath
>   the ribs.

I could understand the link to the number of mentions of Hashem's name in Shema since the Shema precedes the Amidah in the daily prayers. And I could understand the link to the number of  vertebrae in the spine since these vertebrae protrude when we bow in the Amidah. But what is the connection to Psalm 29?

Answer (score 2):

Rashi explains that it is a reference to the *beraita* quoted in Rosh HaShanah 32a, which derives the content of the first three blessings of the *amidah* from the opening words of Tehillim 29.

Comment: Very good - for the first three blessings. Where do we get the others from?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I don't understand your question. Where do we get the number of the other blessings from? Or where do we get what their topics are?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95585/discussion-between-avrohom-yitzchok-and-joel-k).